# Simple class constructor initialization errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, if-statement, for-loop

Using placeholder names in the following code piece could someone please explain why I keep getting a C2065 (apple undeclared identifier) and C2228 (left of .weight/.colour/.price) must have class/struct/union? Surely if the variable matches the declaration it should proceed past the while loop with no issues.

```
int variable = (algorithm that creates a number);

if (variable == certain number)
{
fruitbag1 apple(40,50);
}
else if (variable == another certain number)
{
fruitbag2 apple(25,50);
}

else if (variable == another certain number)
{
fruitbag3 apple(30,50);
}

while (condition)
{
   while (another condition)
   {

   apple.weight();
   apple.colour();
   }
  apple.price();
}
```

I tried this to try to alleviate the problem to no avail with the same errors:

```
int variable = (algorithm that creates a number);

if (variable == certain number)
{
fruitbag1 apple(40,50);
}
else if (variable == another certain number)
{
fruitbag2 apple(25,50);
}

else if (variable == another certain number)
{
fruitbag3 apple(30,50);
}

if (variable is within the range of the certain numbers)
{
    while (condition)
    {
       while (another condition)
       {

       apple.weight();
       apple.colour();
       }
      apple.price();
    }
}
```

**Solution found:**

Longer and inefficient, but works well

```
int variable = (algorithm that creates a number);

if (variable == certain number)
{
fruitbag1 apple(40,50);

while (condition)
    {
       while (another condition)
       {

       apple.weight();
       apple.colour();
       }
      apple.price();
    }



}

if (variable == another certain number)
{
fruitbag2 apple(25,50);

while (condition)
    {
       while (another condition)
       {

       apple.weight();
       apple.colour();
       }
      apple.price();
    }
}

if (variable == another certain number)
{
fruitbag3 apple(30,50);
while (condition)
    {
       while (another condition)
       {

       apple.weight();
       apple.colour();
       }
      apple.price();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The `apple`-class is not found.**

Make sure that you `#include "apple.h"` or similar in your main file.
Otherwise the `apple` class is not found.
If it is defined in the same file' make sure it is defined right **above** the function that uses `apple`.

Comment: Having tried this, I get a lot of C4822 and C2246 errors regarding local class member functions not having a body or because I have a static const int inside the class

Comment: @Vandib probably the class definition contains some errors then, yep

Comment: I would think so too, however if I place say just fruitbag1 apple(40,50); before the while loops with no if statements, it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what's happening here.
But pay attention that `apple` instance is not known in the `whiles` curly brackets..

That may answer the `C2065 (apple undeclared identifier)`.

If you fix it it might solve the other one as well.

For example, you can do this:

```
int variable = (algorithm that creates a number);
...
fruitbag1 *apple = new fruitbag1;
...
if (variable == certain number)
{
    *apple = apple(40,50);
}
...

while (condition)
{
   while (another condition)
   { 

   apple.weight();
   apple.colour();
   }
  apple.price();
}
```

So now It is known in the curly braces...

It is called `scoping`.
try to search for `c++ scope`.

Comment: It doesnt have to be declared inside the while, as long as its not declared inside the if ;-)

Comment: Assuming hudacs solution works, how would I declare apple in the while loop?

Comment: @Vandib declare a `fruitbag apple;` just below the `int variable` and define it in one of the if's. This way you can access it in your while loops as well

Comment: If you do `new` remember to do `delete`. BTW it seems you have 3 kind of `classes` (fruitbag1, 2, 3). I don't know what is your class hierarchy but maybe it is best to use pointers here.

Comment: This way leaks memory, please either don't allocate before the if or cleanup before assigning in the if.

Comment: c scope explanation: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm

Comment: Thanks for the help @hudac however, I appear to get  'fruitbag1' : no appropriate default constructor available followed by other errors

Comment: That's probably because you don't have a `default constructor` for `fruitbag`... you should make one... the most simple is `fruitbag() {};` in the class declaration.. also you might want to have an `operator=`...

Comment: I'm aware of using default constructors but wouldn't using a default constructor for each fruitbag act is if each apple argument were declared without an if loop before the while loops anyway?

Comment: I didn't understand what you wrote. The issue here is the `scope`. `apple` wasn't recognized in the `while()` block cause it was declared inside the `if()` block (which is not contain the `while()` block). One way to solve this is to use pointers, another way is to use an instance and just to copy the desirable values inside the `if()`.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, i'll try using pointers and see if it works, then i'll make this the accepted answer if it's successful

Comment: Great. If you think this was the issue here, but still have other problems you can close this question and open another question about the other specific issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each if-else statement has its own block scope. So any variable defined in the compound statement of if or else is a local variable and will be destroyed after the control will be passed outside the corresponding if or else compound statement.

So after this code snippet

```
if (variable == certain number)
{
fruitbag1 apple(40,50);
}
else if (variable == another certain number)
{
fruitbag2 apple(25,50);
}

else if (variable == another certain number)
{
fruitbag3 apple(30,50);
}
```

here name apple is unknown.

Comment: How would you make it known in that case?

Comment: You can use polymorphism provided that all three classes fruitbag1, fruitbag2, fruitbag3 are derived from one base class. In this case you can define a pointer to the base class and assign it pointers to derived classes.